# Stop Previously running thread which was created in previous class in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I just need to stop a thread which was created in previous run time of the same application. This is the scenario. I'm retrieving data from database for the notification using thread in background, But when I start that application again, number of threads are increasing. I need to stop this. I think its better to stop the background running thread in onCreate() method of the application's main class. But noway to do it. Please help me on this thing as soon as possible.

Thanks and Best Regards,
Shehan.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a static reference to the running Thread in your activity class. Inside your thread you need to have a boolean variable you can set or a method you can call that will cause your thread to complete. In `onCreate()` you can check if you have a running thread, and if so, tell it to stop. Here's a code example:

In your activity:

```
private static Thread myThread;
```

In your activity, when you create the thread:

```
if (myThread != null) {
    if (myThread.isAlive()) {
        myThread.running = false; // Tell the thread to stop running now
    }
}
myThread = new Thread(...);
myThread.start();
```

In your thread:

```
public boolean running = true; // Initator of this thread should set this to false to make the thread complete

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        // do whatever your thread does in a loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the ruuning threads onDestroy() of activity.

please find the below eg:

```
 static boolean stopThread=false;
    public myThread implements Ruunable{
    public void run(){
    while(true){
    //your logic
    if(stopThread)
    break;
    }
    }


    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() 
        {    

          stopThread=true;
        }
```